# No .psd thumbnails in Windows explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

I have an issue with Windows Explorer not displaying PSD files... (photoshop CC 2019 All my PSD files appear as white rectangles, so it's impossible to identify the different files and work efficiently.
I have installed SageThumbs, and the .psd extension is checked in the settings, however it doesn't work. It seems that it stopped displaying the thumbnails after one of the recent Windows 10 updates.
Does anyone has a solution to get the PSD thumbnails back? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling SgaeThumbs after MS disabled it?

Comment: Yes I did, but it still didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Are they multi-layer PSDs? Many systems have difficulty displaying thumbs if the layering is complex. The only 'fix' is to save a small jpg next to each PSD, to act as your 'thumb provider'. Example from a Mac [icon thumbs are off, personal pref, but it can't display even when asked] https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X6DR.png

Comment: Oh I see, I wasn't aware of that. Yes, they are all multi layer files. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Let me drop that in as an answer, just so we have something for future googlers...

Answer (score 0):

It may be that they are multi-layer PSDs.

Many systems have difficulty displaying thumbs if the layering is complex.
The only 'fix' is to save a small jpg next to each PSD, to act as your 'thumb provider'.

Example from a Mac [icon previews are off, personal pref, but it can't display even when asked]

[image]

Sometimes, I'll get one layer showing up - looking odd with its mask but no actual subject -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! What's weird is that I've never had that issue on my MacBook Pro during all the years I've been working with Photoshop (even with complex multi layer files the thumbnails always showed up), and on my second PC (that also has SageThumbs installed and same Windows & Photoshop version), the thumbnails show just fine so it seems that it could be an issue with settings in Windows? I'll see if maybe there's an alternative to SageThumbs that could fix the issue.

Comment: Wish you luck - I've not much experience with it on Win, but on Mac I've always struggled with multi-layers - sometimes I'll see a preview of maybe one layer & its mask. I've added another pic to the answer...